# Update mySQL table based on row=column name

Tags: mysql, sql, database

A little background so you understand what I'm trying to do. I am making a page that takes two user input products and checks to see if they are compatible with one another. This is an n+1*n mySQL table because there are n products.

The table looks like

```
name    a    b    c    d    e
a
b
c
d
e
```

I already know that every product is compatible with itself, so to save time, is there a query that will automatically fill the table out so that I can get

```
name    a    b    c    d    e
a       1
b            1
c                 1
d                      1
e                           1
```

Thanks

I forgot to mention, each product can be compatible with an several other products. The diagonal I'm putting in is just a starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question but I felt I had to mention it...

If possible you should consider changing your design to the following:

```
compatible_products
product1 product2
a        b
a        c
b        d
etc...
```

If you insert rows for both (a, b) and (b, a) then your query is simple:

```
SELECT 1
FROM compatible_products
WHERE product1 = 'a' AND product2 = 'b'
```

Also, when you add new products you won't have to change your database schema.

Comment: I forgot to mention, each product can be compatible with an several other products. Does your answer still apply? (I'm pretty new to mySQL)

Comment: @tom: Yes - in my example table a is compatible with b and c, and b is compatible with d.

Comment: oh good point. thanks.

just to satisfy my curiosity though, is there any way to do it the way I was going?

Comment: @tom: I don't know if it is possible, but if it is it would probably be very unpleasant. SQL is not designed for this sort of operation.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to your question, but this sounds like a design mistake.

This way, you would have to add a new column to your table for every new product that comes up.

I think the much better way would be normalizing the table into one `products` and one `compatibility` table.

Each compatibility relationship between a product and another would be one record.

The `compatibility` table could look like this:

```
id   product1    product2    

0    12          34          
1    33          32          
2    54          1           
3    65          328
```

Queries would become extremely easy. To find out a relationship, you would have to do a simple

```
SELECT id FROM compatibility WHERE (product1 = 18 and product2 = 23) 
                                OR (product1 = 23 and product2 = 18)
```